# Trouble with mod rewrite and slashes and $_GET

Tags: regex, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, trailing-slash

I'm trying to implement nicer urls using mod rewrite to a php script I wrote to view documents pulled from a mysql database by their entry name. i use the following code and it works fine.

```
RewriteRule ^view.doc.(.+)  index.php?doc=$1
```

so basically

> ```
> view.doc.xyz whould be index.php?doc=xyz
> ```

But im having trouble with entry names with '/' and '\' in them being viewed through the rewritten link.

> ```
> view.doc.abc/123 into index.php?doc=abc/123
> ```

or like

> view.doc.sg1\123 into index.php?doc=sg1\123

Ether i'd get an endless loop or get a 404 error. I'm pretty new to mod rewrite and Id very much appreciate any help on the matter.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this rule:

```
RewriteRule ^view\.doc\.(.+)$ index.php?doc=$1 [L,QSA,NE,NC]
```

Comment: yes but it seems that the 404 problem persisted only because the script was working from a sub directory. i simply added the <base> html tag to the document header and your rewrite solution worked quite well.

Answer (score 0):

I propose a slightly different solution from the @anubhava's one, by prepending a slash before index.php, tested on Debian/Apache2:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^view\.doc\.(.+)$ /index.php?doc=$1 [L,QSA,NE,NC]
```

It gives:

view.doc.abc/123 => /index.php?doc=abc/123

I cannot test anti-slash \, as no browser permits me to test this in URL without transforming it to slash /.